# how can call json web services in angular js

Tags: javascript, json

Webservices url

> http://3.srsm-s.appspot.com/trailerScreenOld.php?title=TWFhbiBLYXJhdGU=&_movie_id_=MjIlk4MTU3OA==&year=MjlmxNA==&seckey=g96c1n1m@

Js code

```
var web = angular.module('web',[]);

web.controller('webcont', function($scope,$http) 
{
  $http.get("http://3.srsm-s.appspot.com/trailerScreenOld.php?title=TWFhbiBLYXJhdGU=&_movie_id_=MjIlk4MTU3OA==&year=MjlmxNA==&seckey=g96c1n1m@").success(function(response) 
  {

  $scope.names = response.movie;

  }

  );
});
```

As tried but the service is not loading and not displaying the data

it throws some error

such us

> Page not found
>
> request not initialized

Comment: Please add a plunker, format your code, and provide a valid url... "Oups, something wrong happen..." This is why you don't get your movie list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know so much about the service you connect but load the link in the browse to get the response on and see the result.

```
{"success":0,"message":"Oops SomeThing Went Wrong."}
```

Maybe that's the problem

Comment: thnks you sir for that help